# is there any generic function for add to favorite and home-page for all type of web-browser?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, browser, favorites

Is there any generic function for add to favorite and home-page for all type of web-browser?

Answer (score 1):

No one way, though you can easily create your own utility: http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/01/add-to-favorites-ie-bookmark-firefox.html

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use JavaScript, the C# tag you're using is misleading here, I guess.

- [This SO posting has details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438108).
- [This is another SO posting about the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832846).