# Cross Browser Script to make my website as Home Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website and I would want to ask users to make my website as Home Page. If they click Yes, I would like to run a script that should make my website as the home page of the user's browser. Have got a [Similar Thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832846/i-need-script-in-jquery-that-make-the-page-as-your-default-home-page-website-in) and a solution [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/addhome.htm). However, the solution present in my latter link works only in IE. I need a cross browser script for this.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: as far as I know you cannot manipulate this on other browsers

Comment: Immagine how annoying it would be if this would be possible...

Comment: @meo..I am not doing it automatically but only after user permits it.

Comment: @Nitesh Not every one is nice on the web :) There would be a lot of misuse. Anyway. Its not possible. Everything a script can to that changes settings in the browser i bad.

Comment: Just thought if it could be.. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to do this via code in most browsers as a security measure. If it was, any website you visit could automatically make itself your homepage without your agreement.

The fact old versions of IE let you do this is very much the exception rather than the rule.

If you require this behaviour, you would need to write a step by step guide telling people what toolbar to click on, and where to set their homepage in their browser settings.

Comment: OK..but how does Google/Bing does the same?

Comment: You only see the 'make this my homepage' text when using a browser which is capable of the functionality.

Comment: In your step by step guide you could show a link to your website and say "Drag this to your browser's home button to make this your homepage"

Comment: I have seen it in Firefox and Chrome.I bet!

Comment: @Nitesh does not change the fact that you can't do it for your own website... unless you can convince mozilla, google, apple, opera and microsoft to make an exception for your site :P

Comment: OK..Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: @Tim..Dragging the site on home button and making home page..how can this be done or this is browser's default property?

Comment: @Nitesh this works for all browsers, try it, drag this to the home button: http://www.example.com

Comment: Ok so but how do viruses, and "stuff like toolbars" that sometimes you agree wihout noticing and that changes your homepage, how they do it?

Answer (score 1):

nitesh, google and bing don't do it... any browser that defaults to google or bing or the hewlett packard home page or whatever come pre-packaged with that site as it's home page... the only way to [change](http://www.cashnhits.com/index.php?view=ptp&ref=043823335) this, is manually, either by:

1) high-lighting the address in the address bar and dragging it to the little "[home](http://freebtc247.blogspot.com/)" icon

2) going to the browser's settings and pasting or typing the address

3) installing software package such as yahoo messenger or the like, that changes these settings for you when you agree during the installation process, usually by checking a box and clicking agree