# Setting current page as homepage

Tags: javascript, html

I searched the web in order to find a code for a button what sets current page to homepage - but found nothing usefull. 
Does anyone have this code? 
Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asume you are *not* asking how, you as the user of the browser, to set the homepage; this might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10751061/2612112.

Answer (score 0):

Only old versions of IE support this.